# Returned json file doesnot have the jsonArray then cant get the output from the Android Studio

Tags: android, json

I am using the Android 5.1 for my project, then i try to return the json file from my server which give me the result like this:

```
  [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "asdiasjdaklsj",
        "description": "dfkldjskdhjsfkldjsfkl",
        "owner": "kyaaa",
        "start": "01/27/2016 12:00 AM",
        "end": "01/28/2016 12:01 AM"
      }
]
```

And the result that can use for the android is like this:

```
"employees":[
    {"id":"John", "title":"Doe"}, 
    {"id":"Anna", "title":"Smith"}, 
    {"id":"Peter","title":"Jones"}
]
```

The Json above is the working result in the code that i use, but when i turn to my own Json, then it will return error and the application will stop working. I wonder what is the problem on that.

```
     package net.simplifiedcoding.volleysample;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 9/22/2015.
 */
public class ParseJSON {
    public static String[] ids;
    public static String[] titles;
    public static String[] descriptions;
    public static String[] owners;
    public static String[] starts;
    public static String[] ends;


    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String KEY_OWNER = "owner";
    public static final String KEY_START = "start";
    public static final String KEY_END = "end";


    private JSONArray users = null;

    private String json;

    public ParseJSON(String json){
        this.json = json;
    }

    protected void parseJSON(){
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

            ids = new String[users.length()];
            titles = new String[users.length()];
            descriptions = new String[users.length()];
            owners = new String[users.length()];
            starts = new String[users.length()];
            ends = new String[users.length()];



            for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
                ids[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);
                titles[i] = jo.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                descriptions[i] = jo.getString(KEY_DESCRIPTION);
                owners[i] = jo.getString(KEY_OWNER);
                starts[i] = jo.getString(KEY_START);
                ends[i] = jo.getString(KEY_END);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And then the application didnt work and stop working, then i just find out the problem is like this. My server doesnot return the json array back to me, but inside the android studio, it need the jsonarray so then can perform pull the data to my phone. Can any one tell me is that any others way can pull the data which does not have the json array on that?Thanks

Comment: your webservice is returning a `JSONArray`. Why are you trying to create  `JSONObejct` from it?

Comment: I have edited my question, you might more understand it. @Blackbelt

Comment: I don't understand how the two things are connected

Comment: @Blackbelt my question is when i try to get the data from my server, it cannot pull down and use in my listview. Then i am thinking maybe is the result that i return is not fullfill the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In json [] represent array and {} represent object. You should take JsonArray first then you will able to iterate on object.

Comment: So thats mean, the code is working fines? But just the result that i return is not working fine right? But the way, in the laravel what should i do and then can return with the json array?

Answer (score 0):

Your server response seems to be an array and not an object, try doing this change instead of casting it into a JSONObject and then trying to get a JSONArray out of it.

```
JSONArray users = new JSONArray(json);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: After i changed it, it still comes out with the errors.

Comment: What error do you get? Also, can you show me what `json` is?

Comment: I meant can you paste the string  `json` that you are using? that might help debug better

Comment: Ya, its all on the question. Because i have added the whole code on my ParseJSON.java

Comment: And you are passing a string manually or is it a server response? A log or a print of that string is what i meant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102152/discussion-between-shubhankar-s-and-ben).